# cakephp issue with read()

Tags: cakephp

Hi this is a cakephp issue that I am facing.

I added a field company in tbl_promos

when I try to read data  `$this->data = $this->Promo->read(null, $id);`  using this.  It does not throw value on company in the array

cheers!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the app is running with `debug` set to `0` you'll probably need to clear the `/app/tmp/cache/models` cache before Cake becomes aware of the new database structure.

Comment: totally worked

I cleared out the cached and issue is gone .. thanks heaps :)